# Add temp rows to table

Tags: sql, oracle

I worked out this SQL Statement...

```
  select 
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XY" LIKE '%XP Pro%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blabla,        
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XYZ" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablabla,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "ABS" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablalasba        
    from 
    table1
    UNION ALL
    select 
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XY" LIKE '%XP Pro%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blabla,        
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XYZ" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablabla,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "ABS" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablalasba        
    from 
    table2
    UNION ALL
    select 
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XY" LIKE '%XP Pro%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blabla,        
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XYZ" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablabla,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "ABS" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablalasba        
    from 
    table3
```

... which gives me the following output:

```
blabla          blablabla         blablalasba

10              23                454545
123             2323              445445
123             212               121221
```

I want to add an extra column with some text in it.

My final result should be:

```
             blabla          blablabla         blablalasba

text1        10              23                454545
text2        123             2323              445445
text3        123             212               121221
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are "Columns" not "Rows".  You can add static text like the following:

```
 select 'text1' text,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XY" LIKE '%XP Pro%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blabla,        
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XYZ" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablabla,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "ABS" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablalasba        
    from 
    table1
    UNION ALL
    select 'text2' text,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XY" LIKE '%XP Pro%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blabla,        
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XYZ" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablabla,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "ABS" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablalasba        
    from 
    table2
    UNION ALL
    select 'text3' text,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XY" LIKE '%XP Pro%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blabla,        
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XYZ" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablabla,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "ABS" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablalasba        
    from 
    table3
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the text at each section of the UNION:

```
  select 
        'text1' AS ColumnTitle
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XY" LIKE '%XP Pro%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blabla,        
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XYZ" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablabla,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "ABS" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablalasba        
    from 
    table1
    UNION ALL
    select 
        'text2' AS ColumnTitle
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XY" LIKE '%XP Pro%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blabla,        
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XYZ" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablabla,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "ABS" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablalasba        
    from 
    table2
    UNION ALL
    select 
        'text3' AS ColumnTitle
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XY" LIKE '%XP Pro%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blabla,        
        SUM(CASE WHEN "XYZ" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablabla,
        SUM(CASE WHEN "ABS" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blablalasba        
    from 
    table3
```